# How to use basemap and matplotlib to display only a detailed map of a country?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I used this code to draw 2 latitude and longitude coordinates on the world map:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
m = Basemap(projection='robin', lon_0=0, resolution='l')
lats = [24.48237852, 26.89169118]
lons = [118.1558955, 117.1760012]
m.drawcountries(color='#ffffff', linewidth=0.5)
m.fillcontinents(color='#c0c0c0', lake_color='#ffffff')
x, y = m(lons, lats)
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', color='r', markersize=5)
plt.show()
```

These two points are in China. I want to display only the map of China, so that the map of China looks larger and more detailed. These two points can be seen more clearly. How to do it?
[image]

Comment: You might want to use `shapefile` of china

Comment: Can you give me a example?

Comment: look at this https://www.programmersought.com/article/82031042577/ If you just want map of china then you dont need shapefile but if you need states and city coordinates then you would require shapefile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Karthik said,now I can draw on the map of China:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
m= Basemap(llcrnrlon=77, llcrnrlat=14, urcrnrlon=140, urcrnrlat=51, projection='lcc', lat_1=33, lat_2=45, lon_0=100) 
m.readshapefile(r'gadm36_CHN_shp/gadm36_CHN_1', 'states', drawbounds = True)
lats = [24.48237852, 26.89169118]
lons = [118.1558955, 117.1760012]
m.drawcountries(color='#ffffff', linewidth=0.5)
m.fillcontinents(color='#c0c0c0', lake_color='#ffffff')
x, y = m(lons, lats)
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', color='r', markersize=5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot only 1 country, `robin` projection has no benefit over the other projections. And Basemap does not allow you to do so anyway. I recommend `merc` (Mercator) projection as a starter. If you have any specific requirements on the map projection to use, that will be another topic. Assuming Mercator projection is used, your code with some of my modification is as follows.

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ll_lon, ur_lon, ll_lat, ur_lat = 72, 136, 16, 54
m = Basemap(projection='merc', lon_0=0, resolution='l',
            llcrnrlon = ll_lon, urcrnrlon = ur_lon,
            llcrnrlat = ll_lat, urcrnrlat = ur_lat,
           )
lats = [24.48237852, 26.89169118]
lons = [118.1558955, 117.1760012]
m.drawcountries(color='#ffffff', linewidth=0.5)
m.fillcontinents(color='#c0c0c0', lake_color='#ffffff')
x, y = m(lons, lats)
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo', color='r', markersize=5)

plt.show()
```

You will get this plot:

[image: china_on_merc]